# How to display specific information extracted from a database

Tags: sql-server

Supposing we have the table below:

T1: ID,  Name, Family_name,    Manager_ID

Knowing that Manager_ID's name exists in the same table T1, how can i display a new table on SQL SERVER where i will have the following columns:

ID,  Manager_ID,   Manager_Name,     Manager_Family_Name

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: I see that you're new to the site. You should probably include what you've attempted since at the moment it seems like a "do my homework for me" kind of question.

Comment: Hi @Y.Joey, welcome to **StackOverflow**, you may take a look to [_"how to ask"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this and future questions. Specially you should provide some [_"research effort"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and/or some code, to prove you already tried to solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you go through SQL 101.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `LEFT JOIN`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name VARCHAR(45),
  FamilyName VARCHAR(45),
  ManagerID INT,
  CONSTRAINT FK_T_ManagerID FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES T(ID)
  );

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1, 'Name1', 'FName1', NULL),
(2, 'Name2', 'FName2', 1);

SELECT *
FROM T T1 LEFT JOIN T T2
ON T1.ManagerID = T2.ID
```